# How to form feature matrix in face recognition algorithms

Tags: image-processing, face-recognition

I read on internet that we can identify faces using either distance metrics (distances between parts of the face) and also using mean, variance and skewness of RGB values and texture features. I would like to know if there are any other metrics for differentiating between faces of different persons.

Comment: This is a massive field of research. The best thing for you to do is to read some [survey papers](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=face+recognition+survey&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart) that will summarize the various approaches.

Comment: Try to Google "Handbook of Face Recognition".... you will get free books from Google Research & Many other Research labs.. Just see the index page you will come to know most of the popular techniques.